# Simplest form for sum of Binomial Expressions

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How difficult is the problem of reducing the number of terms in a sum of binomial expressions? Formally:

Given $a_1, a_2, a_3, … a_n$, and $b_1, b_2, b_3, ... , b_n$, where $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a_i, b_i \geq 0$, consider

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {s-a_i \choose r-b_i}$$

For all integers $s, r \geq max(a_1, a_2, a_3, … a_n, b_1, b_2, b_3, ... , b_n)$, where ${x \choose y}=0$ for all $y>x$, and ${x \choose 0}=1$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Goal: Find the smallest size $m$ such that, for $c_1, c_2, c_3, … c_m, d_1, d_2, d_3, ... , d_m$, where $c_i, d_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $c_i, d_i \geq 0$

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {s-a_i \choose r-b_i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m {s-c_i \choose r-d_i}$$

For all integers $s, r \geq max(a_1, a_2, … a_n, b_1, b_2, ... , b_n, c_1, c_2, ..., c_m, d_1, d_2, ... d_m)$.

Alternatively, find $c_i$ and $d_i$ such that $m$ is as small as possible.

For example:

- ${s-1 \choose r-1} + {s-1 \choose r} = {s \choose r}$ (Using Pascal's Triangle)
- Any linear dependence $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n α_i {r−a_i \choose s−b_i}=0$ valid for all sufficiently large $r$,$s$ is a linear combination of the Pascal triangle identities ${r−a+1 \choose s−b+1} − {r−a \choose s−b+1} − {r−a \choose s−b}=0$

Do we know if any complexity bounds/computability bounds are known for this problem in general?

I'm also interested in the alternate problem where we're allowed integer constants $e_i, f_i \geq 0$, and we're still interested in finding the smallest size $m$ such that

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {s-a_i \choose r-b_i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m {e_i\cdot s-c_i \choose f_i\cdot r-d_i}$$

However I'm primarily interested in the first problem - I just mention this second problem partially in case there is a trivial solution to the first that I'm not aware of.

Comment: In your original sum, `$n$' occurs both as the upper summation limit and in the binomial coefficient. Is this intentional?

Comment: Sorry! No it was not. I edited the question now.

Comment: For the second more general problem, you can insure m=1 by picking d = fr-1.  The first problem looks less trivial to me.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, but it is not hard to prove that any linear dependence $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\binom{r-a_i}{s-b_i}=0$ valid for all sufficiently large $r,s$ is a linear combination of the Pascal triangle identities $\binom{r-a+1}{s-b+1}-\binom{r-a}{s-b+1}-\binom{r-a}{s-b}=0$.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger, I think you're misunderstanding the question. In both problems, all $d_i$s and $f_i$s must be a constant (not dependent on $r$), and the relation must hold for any $r$ and $s$ greater than all $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$. Thus means $d_i$ can never equal $f_i r-1$ for all $r$ unless $f=0$. I might be misunderstanding your comment though.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, yes, there are many such identities. It's possible that maybe just compiling a list of all of them - then proving that that list is comprehensive - would be sufficient to solve this problem, but I'm not sure if such a list can be constructed. Also that might just turn it into an NP-Hard or NP-Complete approximation algorithm of needing to "choose the right identities," however I'm not aware of any results showing either - so it's possible that maybe such a list of identities would be constructive in actually providing this reduction efficiently, I'm not sure.

Comment: Now that I have read your comments, can you explain to me how your second bulleted example is an example of the problem?  It seems the dependence on r makes it not an example.

Comment: @DaniPhye: I think you misunderstood what I said. There is a complete list, and it consists of instances of the Pascal triangle identity. Whether this can give an efficient solution I don't know, but it sort of reduces the problem to linear algebra (find a 0-1 vector of minimal norm in a particular affine space).

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger You're actually very right, sorry. I removed it now and replaced it with Emil's example.

Comment: No problem.  Even though I misunderstood your intent (so that my trivial solution does not apply to the general question), I think there are two ways to take my answer and fully bake it.  One is to choose several pairs s and r before applying the algorithm, and the other is to change representation: Pick A large enough, represent each of the n summands as a sum of terms (s-A) choose i, add all those "vectors" of length s-A+1 together, and then try the greedy strategy as before.  This may only give you an upper bound on m, but it may suggest something else of low time complexity to try.

Comment: For sake of increased clarity, you might add after the word formally: let s and r be variables, and for fixed numerical values of a's and b's consider the function P(s,r) in s and r given by sum.  I want to rewrite P(s,r) as a similar sum in fewer terms of s and r, as follows...  This way it is more clear to me that the desired identity holds for s and r sufficiently large integers, and perhaps even for s and r small enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum: I misread the problem, not paying attention to the for all s and r.  Thus the trivial
answer to the second more general question trivially misses the intent.  However, one can
change the problem representation by picking A large enough, encoding each of the n
summands as a vector which, dotted with the vector whose ith component is (s-A) choose i,
sums to that summand, and then add all the vectors together and try the greedy algorithm
below on the summed vector.  Another approach is to try the algorithm with several
specific choices for r and s, and try to deduce a new sum based on the results.  This
approach I see as akin to checking for a symbolic determinant being identically 0 or
not by plugging in numerical values and evaluating the determinant numerically.  So I
say without proof but with evidence that the below algorithm respects the intent of the question.
End of Addendum.

Here is a half baked approach.  Compute the total T of the n terms, and subtract multiples of
s choose r until the result S is less than s choose r.  As the central binomial coefficients grow like
powers of 2, a greedy approach should get you an m of the order r log s.  Now if needed, try
minimizing the greedy sum S of m terms by choosing slightly less greedy choices smaller than s choose r.

As observed in a comment, the more general problem has enough freedom to admit a trivial or
nearly trivial solution, with bottom coefficient equal to m which is equal to 1.

Comment: I assume 2r is less than s in the above.  If this is not the case, tweak the algorithm more greedily.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding what this algorithm does, I believe it has the same problem as your comment earlier: the relation must hold for all s and r > all the constants, not just for fixed values of s and r. If this wasn't the case, the problem would be trivial - simply compute the total T of the n terms, call this w, and return w choose 1, aka m=1. I assume this is what you meant in your comment (since you can't do _ choose 1 in the first problem but you can in the second), however this method isn't valid for either because s and r aren't constants.

Comment: Though this answer would be a good algorithm for solving the first problem as well in a similar fashion, if s and r were constants, you're right.